# How do i compare each column on different datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

Let say I have 2 datagridview fullrowselect and each of them has two columns.for example like this one

```
      DGV1                    DGV2
ControlNum|Title        ControlNum|Title 
0132      |avengers     0112      |X-men
0112      |X-men        0231      |Transformers
0234      |spiderman    0123      |Thor
```

now I want to compare Dvg2's list to DGV1 if DGV2 contains the same data in dgv1 then i want to color the background cell of that row in dgv2 into red if not remain as is..
code for loading db

```
 void loadDB()//dgv1
    {
        string query = "SELECT animelist.ControlNum,TitleAnime FROM maindatabase.watchlist inner join maindatabase.animelist on watchlist.ControlNum = animelist.ControlNum where idnum=?para;";
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
        {                
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?para",int.Parse(MyList.AccountControlNum.ToString()));
                try
                {
                    this.Controls.Add(grid);

                    sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    datset = new DataTable();
                    grid.DataSource = datset;
                    sda.Fill(datset);
                    bsource = new BindingSource();
                    grid.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Kurumi;
                    grid.SetCellsTransparent();
                    grid.Width = 271;
                    grid.Height = 391;
                    grid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                    grid.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
                    grid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                    grid.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
                    grid.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
                    grid.ReadOnly = true;
                    grid.AllowDrop = false;
                    grid.MultiSelect = false;
                    grid.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
                    grid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
                    grid.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
                    grid.Sort(grid.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
                    DataGridViewColumn column = grid.Columns[0];
                    column.Visible = false;
                    try
                    {
                        grid.CurrentCell = grid[1, 0];
                    }
                    catch { }
                    my = this.Parent.Parent as MyList;
                    my.label5.Text = grid.RowCount.ToString();
                    DataGridViewColumn column1 = grid.Columns[1];
                    column1.HeaderText = "WatchList";
                   // column1.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = MiddleCenter;
                    column1.Width = 265;
                    sda.Update(datset);
                    grid.SelectionChanged += grid_SelectionChanged;
                    grid.CellMouseDown += grid_CellMouseDown;

                    if (grid.RowCount < 1)
                    {
                        my.OpenDetailsWL.Enabled = false;
                        //openToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else if (grid.RowCount > 0)
                    {
                        my.OpenDetailsWL.Enabled = true;
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

dgv 2

```
void loadDB()
    {
        SuspendLayout();
        string query = "SELECT ControlNum,TitleAnime FROM maindatabase.animelist";
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                try
                {

                    panel5.Controls.Add(grid);

                    sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    datset = new DataTable();
                    grid.DataSource = datset;
                    sda.Fill(datset);
                    bsource = new BindingSource();
                    grid.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.My;
                    grid.SetCellsTransparent();
                    grid.Width = 271;
                    grid.Height = 391;
                    grid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                    grid.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
                    grid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                    grid.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
                    grid.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
                    grid.ReadOnly = true;
                    grid.AllowDrop = false;
                    grid.MultiSelect = false;
                    grid.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
                    grid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
                    grid.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
                    grid.Sort(grid.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
                    //bsource.DataSource = datset;
                    //dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
                    DataGridViewColumn column = grid.Columns[0];
                    column.Visible = false;
                    try
                    {
                        grid.CurrentCell = grid[1, 0];
                    }
                    catch { }
                    label2.Text= grid.RowCount.ToString();
                    DataGridViewColumn column1 = grid.Columns[1];
                    column1.Width = 265;
                    column1.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
                    sda.Update(datset);
                    grid.SelectionChanged += grid_SelectionChanged;
                    grid.CellMouseDown += grid_CellMouseDown;
                    if (grid.RowCount < 1)
                    {
                        openToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else if (grid.RowCount > 0)
                    {
                        openToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: you start off by first writing some code and or showing what you have  tried this is not a `Code Factory`  also your first move should have been to do a simple google search  site. good luck

Comment: Just to give you a starting point: You should look into comparing the underlying datasource item collections and update a hidden column carrying the status info to be able to bind your styling (red) to this column.

Comment: I do have codes its just that i dont know if that code really helps its just loading the datagridview,ok i'll post it if you want methodman

Comment: You should narrow down the code a bit - this is much to much to expect the SO community to dissect.

Comment: You start deleting pieces of your code, until the error goes away, then you add that part back, and we can debug that part.

Comment: Seeing your the database queries behind your datagrids: Why would you need to compare them at this stage at all? You simply extend your query to contain a column carrying the info you need to highlight the respective records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your List 1 contains your `watchlist` table; your List 2 contains your `animelist` table.

If you retrieve both lists from the same database and want to highlight records being in both source tables in your `animelist` list you can solve this simply by outer join your `watchlist` table:

dgv2 query:

```
SELECT
  animelist.ControlNum AS 'ControlNum',
  animelist.TitleAnime AS 'Title',
  IFNULL(watchlist.ControlNum, 0) AS 'WatchNum'
FROM maindatabase.animelist
LEFT JOIN maindatabase.watchlist ON watchlist.ControlNum = animelist.ControlNum
```

next you'll have to register an event handler on your grid to control the cell formatting:

```
grid.CellFormatting += grid_CellFormatting;
```

the event handler will look something like this:

```
void grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ControlNum")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            int controlnum;
            if (!int.TryParse((String)e.Value, out controlnum) || (controlnum < 1))
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[A full example can be found on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/957khz2k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

*I'm no mysql pro so the query surly can be improved.*